# C - compiler asks to use '->' when already using '->'

Tags: c

I'm working through an exercise in the K&R the C language book and am having a strange problem with the compiling.

The compiler tells me to use -> operator for a pointer although I'm already using one.

Here is the function that has the problem with compiling :

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} node; 

int pop (node **stack) {
  node *poped_node;
  char poped_char;
  if (*stack == NULL) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    poped_node = *stack;
    poped_char = stack -> data; //These are
    *stack = stack -> next; // the problematic lines.
    free(poped_node);
    return poped_char;
  }
}
```

These is what the compiler returns:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘pop’:
test.c:71:24: error: ‘*stack’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
     poped_char = stack -> data;
                        ^~
                        ->
test.c:72:20: error: ‘*stack’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
     *stack = stack -> next;
                    ^~
                    ->
```

Also I use the same operator in other function in a similar way and it doesn't show any problem with the compiling there.

Comment: `stack` is a double pointer. You need two dereferences to use it, for example `(*stack)->data`

Comment: That is a poor compiler message. Which compiler is it?

Comment: I'm using cygwin in windows

Comment: yeah, somehow it is transformed into the same parse tree `(*stack).data` *before* this message is generated; for `(*stack).data`  it makes sense

Answer (score 3):

The compiler message is about `*stack`being a pointer, not `stack`.

```
poped_char = stack -> data; //These are
*stack = stack -> next; // the problematic lines.
```

You are using `stack` as if it was a pointer to some struct. Instead it is a pointer to a pointer to struct.

Changing these lines like this should solve your problem:

```
poped_char = (*stack) -> data; //These are
*stack = (*stack) -> next; // the problematic lines.
```

Comment: I think I understand my mistake.
Could you tell me why there is a difference between *stack and (*stack)? The compiler runs one but not the other.

Comment: The difference is with operator precedence. `*stack->data` is equivalent to `*(stack->data)` which is not what you want.